# Nginx sending 301 when using proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a website hosted on AWS, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). I have created a blog on Wix myblog.wixsite.com/blog. Now, I want to show the contents of myblog.wixsite.com/blog on [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog). So I used the following Nginx conf to try & achieve that.

```
location /blog/ {
          sub_filter 'http://myblog.wixsite.com/' 'https://$http_host/blog/';
          sub_filter 'https://myblog.wixsite.com/' 'https://$http_host/blog/';
          sub_filter 'href="/posts/' 'href="/blog/';
          sub_filter 'href="/category/' 'href="/blog/category/';
          sub_filter 'href="/authors/' 'href="/blog/authors/';
          sub_filter 'href="/recent/' 'href="/blog/recent/';

          proxy_ssl_verify off;
          proxy_set_header Host "myblog.wixsite.com";
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host "";
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For "";
          proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
          proxy_set_header Cookie "";

          proxy_pass http://myblog.wixsite.com/blog/;

          proxy_redirect ~^(http://[^/]+)(/.+)$ https://$http_host$2;
        }
```

Now, when I hit [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog), Nginx redirects me to https://myblog.wixsite.com/blog/ instead of showing the content on [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog) itself. I also tried changing
`proxy_pass http://myblog.wixsite.com/blog/;` to
`proxy_pass https://myblog.wixsite.com/blog/;`
but I started getting the following error.

```
*532 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: <redacted>, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /blog/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://myblog.wixsite.com/blog/", host: "www.example.com"
```

I have been at it for a couple of days with no results. Can someone suggest what might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use [`proxy_redirect`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) or change

> ```
> proxy_pass http://myblog.wixsite.com/blog/; to
> ```

> ```
> proxy_pass https://myblog.wixsite.com/blog/;
> ```

Notice the protocol is `https` instead of `http`. Your wix blog is served on HTTPS anyway.

Comment: I tried doing this as well but got stuck at an SSL Handshake error. I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: Try setting [`proxy_ssl_server_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_server_name) to `on`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not nginx that sends the redirect, it is the website `https://myblog.wixsite.com/blog/` that sends the redirect, nginx only proxies the response it gets from the site.

Comment: Is there a way to stop that from happening?